# Create an angularjs directive that accepts default settings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to create a directive that could be initialized with some default settings when the app is initializing (not when added to a page).

Then when used in a page this directive would use these settings (if they were set) to override its internal defaults.

Saying this in a different way, I want to be able to set properties on a directive in the application level, to avoid setting them on each instance

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ i.e. uib-tooltip has such settings

Answer (score 0):

One option I found to do this, is to create a new directive, wrapping the one in question. In this new directive we will get the global app setting, and provide it to the internal directive.

In this way we can avoid providing the setting value in each page the directive is used in.